# GAE: Data is lost after dev server restart

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running App Engine with Python 2.7 on OS X. Once I stop the development server all data in the data store is lost. Same thing happens when I try to deploy my app. What might cause this behaviour and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the local datastore is reseted from now and then, if you don't want this behaviour you should set the `--datastore_path` when you are starting your dev server from a command line. Something like this would work:

```
dev_appserver.py /path/to/project --datastore_path=/path/to/project/datastore
```

Comment: @LarsVegas This is by design. I'm not sure if you really want that in the long run.. think about it when you'll have users and real data... do you really want to have your local/test data being uploaded all the time on the real thing?

Comment: I guess it depends. In this case absolutely yes. Isn't there an option to allow your test data to be uploaded optionally?

Comment: @LarsVegas not really.. you could use the Remote API to do something on your own.. maybe having some automated things to fill your datastore.. but simply transferring your local datastore to the server it is not possible. (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi)

Comment: I used the remote api by calling a script a uploaded with the app. It all went smooth. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered, but to explain a little further - the local datastore, by default writes to the temporary file system on your computer. By default, the temporary file is emptied any time you restart the computer, hence your datastore is emptied. If you don't restart your computer, your datastore should remain.